# Get the coordinates of a Touch/Press on the Siri Remote's trackpad itself

Tags: objective-c, swift, touch, tvos, apple-tv

I know that we can detect the area of a press on the TrackPad using:

- UIPressType.UpArrow
- UIPressType.DownArrow
- UIPressType.LeftArrow
- UIPressType.RightArrow

But I'm wondering: Is it possible to get the actual coordinates of a user's touch on the Siri Remote's trackpad itself?

Answer (score 0):

So, you can detect a user's panning using the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and [`translationInView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPanGestureRecognizer/translationInView%3A)

But the unfortunate thing is that the new Apple TV remote doesn't discriminate with where the first touch originates on the touchpad. It always counts it as `(0,0)` and then uses the change in `x` and `y` position to determine the swipe direction. So, unfortunately you can't do cool things like "if they tap at the very top left corner once" or "if they swipe from the left edge to the right do something different than a regular right swipe"

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A touch on the track pad always starts in the center of the view wether you touch the center or the edge. Therefore the initial touch will be a `CGPoint` with the coordinates of your views center.